# Fast Static Circles in a Dynamic Image using imshow() and matplotlib.patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, movie, imshow

I cleaned up my code in order to ask this question, then found the solution while I was cleaning it up.  See my solution below.

I'm trying to create a dynamic image (a movie) in `imshow()` with static circles drawn on top of it using `matplotlib.patches`, but it's slowing down as the movie plays (the latency is increasing linearly with time).  The circles are static, so there must be a way to make `matplotlib.patches` run faster as `imshow()` is updating.  Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

# Radius for circle of circles
r = 0.5
# Number of circles
n = 7
# Locations of centers of circles
a = r*np.transpose(np.array([np.cos(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/n)),
                             np.sin(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/n))]))

# Create first background image.
E = toeplitz(np.random.rand(70))

# Plot the first frame.
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(E,extent=np.array([-1,1,-1,1]))
# Draw the circles on the image
for k in range(np.shape(a)[0]):
    ax.add_patch(Circle((a[k][0],a[k][1]),0.1))
plt.show()

# Update with background image and redraw the circles.
for t in range(60):
    # Update the background image.
    E=toeplitz(np.random.rand(70)) 
    im.set_array(E)
    # Update the circles
    for k in range(np.shape(a)[0]):
        ax.add_patch(Circle((a[k][0],a[k][1]),0.1))
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a pretty simple solution.  The `add_patch()` function only needs to run once at the beginning of the movie, and `set_array` updates the array behind the circles.  Here is the code with the `add_patch()` function removed from the main `for` loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

# Radius for circle of circles
r = 0.5
# Number of circles
n = 7
# Locations of centers of circles
a = r*np.transpose(np.array([np.cos(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/n)),
                             np.sin(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/n))]))

# Create first background image.
E = toeplitz(np.random.rand(70))

# Plot the first frame.
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(E,extent=np.array([-1,1,-1,1]))
# Draw the circles on the image
for k in range(np.shape(a)[0]):
    ax.add_patch(Circle((a[k][0],a[k][1]),0.1))
plt.show()

# Update with background image.
for t in range(60):
    E=toeplitz(np.random.rand(70)) 
    im.set_array(E)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

This runs with nearly constant time.  Hopefully this will save someone else a couple of hours of debugging in the future.